# RavenDB faceted search and creating breadcrumbs/filter urls in mvc3

Tags: ravendb, faceted-search

I am using mvc3 and RavenDB. I have a filter menu where users can narrow
their search using faceted search, as described here: 
http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/faceted-search

I like to have this URL pattern: `/filter/{manufacturer}/{resolution}/{zoom}`
For example: `/filter/canon/6` means list all camera's of manufacturer canon with
a megapixel of 6 (and all zoom ranges).

I have this working but I run into trouble generating URLs. This will only
work if the facet values are safe to use in a URL eg. replace all ampersands, 
spaces etc with a dash and lower case everything. This means I end up 
with 'ugly' names in my filtermenu links and breadcrumbs.

**Is there a way to have a friendly name to display to the user for a facet value?** 
so I can create urls like this:

```
<a href="/filter/canon/">Canon USA (12)</a>
<a href="/filter/canon/6/">6 megapixels (5)</a>
```

One solution I can think of would be to store the filters as documents 
and just search for a facet value to retrieve its displayname.

A filter document can look like this:

```
var filter = new Filter
                 {
                   DisplayName = "Manufacturer" ,
                   Slug = "manufacturer" ,
                   Items = new List< FilterItem >
                        {
                            new FilterItem() { DisplayName = "Canon USA" , Slug = "canon" } ,                    
                            new FilterItem() { DisplayName = "Photo's & more" , Slug = "photos-and-more" }
                        }
                 } ;
```

Comment: what have you used to implement the breadcrumb menu? ASP.NET MVC SiteMap provider? I'm interested because I can't find any sample out there...

Comment: I am not using the sitemap provider. Because my routes are mostly linear/predictable I generate a list of URLs in my controllers which are rendered by a partial view in my layout file. When the user makes the jump to a product page I pass the current breadcrumb trail via tempdata because different routes can lead to the same product page.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew,
Yes, that is probably what you want to do. In general, since you control the values, you can control what those will be, but there is no reason to make things hard globally. You can just store the values somewhere and map between them.
It would be easier all around.